# make it so multiple matching location blocks are handled

Tags: php, nginx

In my nginx conf.d file I have the following:

```
  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location ^~ /dev/ {
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE display_errors=On;
  }
```

My goal was to have it so *.php was parsed by PHP in any directory, including the /dev/ directory and that, within the /dev/ directory, display_errors would be enabled. But it seems that the locations aren't being ANDed together but rather ORd. So if it matches *.php it parses it as a PHP file unless it's in the /dev/ directory.

Do I have to be redundant and have the PHP config code duplicated twice or is there a way I can avoid that redundancy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to be redundant. Except in very limited circumstances, `location` blocks are only parsed once, and the closest match wins.

Though you can reduce the pain of this by removing the common configuration parameters to a separate file and then using `include` to include it in both places.